# ActionListener to refresh JFrame from a Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm a java beginner, and I'm now on the GUI.

My problem is that to make my gui I've made several panel in different classes like connexion panel, menu panel etc... and for each panel I've a button  which should interact with my `JFrame` window. So I don't know for example how the button in the menu will interact with my `JFrame` window (which is in a different class) to refresh it and then to put another panel to replace it .If someone can help  please?

Comment: Please share some of your code so we can help you further

Comment: Just pass a reference to the JFrame to the listener (better trigger some controller but that might be beyond your skill right now) and replace the panel, e.g. by placing the new panel at the old one's within the layout manager.

Answer (score 4):

> i'm a java beginner , and i'm now on the GUI , my problem is that to
>   make my gui

- please to read offical Oracle tutorials [Using Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) before asking a question here in [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

> i've made several panel in different class like connexion panel , menu
>   panel etc.... and for each panel i've a button which should interact
>   with my JFrame window .So i don't know for exemple how the button in
>   the menu will interact with my JFrame window (which is in a different
>   class )to refresh it and then to put another panel to replace it

- seems like as [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) is best solution without unwanted side effects

Comment: It seems like a _link-only-answer_

Comment: I like how you quote the _"I'm a beginner"_ and link directly to the tuts. I might make a habit of doing that also :-)

Comment: @ambigram_maker I think the definition of link-only answers is contextual. In this context I think it's fine since it links to the official tutorial site and the effort put into answering the question matches well with the OP's effort in asking the question :)

Comment: @ambigram_maker: Right, but they're the _right_ links!